# Mercurial - why doesn't diff work?

Tags: mercurial, diff

I have just started to use mercurial (for windows). According to the tutorial http://hginit.com/01.html I made repository, etc. But diff command doesn't show any changes that I made in files. Do you have any ideas what is wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to provide the command line you're using and the result you're getting exactly if you want to allow us to help you.

Comment: did you do `hg commit` before doing `hg diff`? if so, there won't be any changes shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, if the command `hg diff` will show differences between the working directory, and its parent. As nye17 suggested, if you have committed some changes just prior to running `hg diff` then the working directory will be the same as its parent, and show no output.  In these instances, you can see what changes were made in by running `hg diff -c -1`.  This will run the hg diff command on the previous (`-1`) changeset.

Answer (score 2):

Basic steps are as follows:

```
hg init .       ---- This make the current directory as blank hg repository

echo "XYZ" > test.txt   --- This creates a new file which is not added to version control yet.

hg add test.txt --- The file is added to repo for commit

hg commit test.txt -m "added file test.txt"  --- Now you can commit the file

hg log  ----- to see the log

hg diff test.txt ----- will show no diff as the latest file committed is same

echo "TTTT" >> test.txt   ----- make some changes

hg diff test.txt   -------- should show the difference of current file to latest in commit

hg commit test.txt -m "second commit"  ----- now once you have committed, latest in repo and working directory is same

hg diff test.txt ------ this diff should again be blank
```